# Can I suppress the browser’s login prompt on 401 response when using XmlHttpRequest with Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, twitter

I'm using jQuery's ajax methods to interact with the [Twitter REST API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/REST+API+Documentation).

Their API is a bit annoying, in that some actions will return a 401 HTTP status code.  In that case, I just want it to fail, instead of displaying a login box.

I've tried just providing an incorrect user:pass pair in the URL, in case that might suppress the dialog and just get me an error response, but that failed to help.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361467/is-there-any-way-to-suppress-the-browsers-login-prompt-on-401-response-when-usi) asked exactly the same question, but the answer instead worked out how to not trigger the 401 in the first place.

(In particular this is annoying because it's a bug on their part that's requesting authentication -- the `users/show` method isn't supposed to be asking for it in the first place.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into suppress_response_codes

It is explained about 1/4 way down the page here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know

From the Twitter documentation (incase it is moved again):

> suppress_response_codes: If this
>   parameter is present, all responses
>   will be returned with a 200 OK status
>   code - even errors.  This parameter
>   exists to accommodate Flash and
>   JavaScript applications running in
>   browsers that intercept all non-200
>   responses.  If used, it's then the job
>   of the client to determine error
>   states by parsing the response body. 
>   Use with caution, as those error
>   messages may change.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that.  I'd still like some general way to avoid the issue entirely, but that definitely solves my problem.

Comment: twitter has moved their documentation. please include the gist of the solution in the stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Updated it again since it's been changed again, not sure it's worth it though for 651 total views in 3 years.